# How to do Static routing EC2 linux-based VM and CSR 1000v

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, linux-networking, amazon-vpc

I'm having the following.
In VPC 1, there are CSR 1000v and EC2 linux-based VM.

[image]

I would like to do static route in order that VM1 and CSR could connect to each other. 
I'm allowing all ICMP traffic in both security groups.

I started with CSR where I had `ip route 172.0.1.16 255.255.255.240 172.0.1.29` but I could not ping VM1 from CSR1

As well as from the VM1 `route add -net 172.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 gw 172.0.1.29 eth0`. It did not work, though.

Comment: You should not need any routes for this these two devices to communicate.  VPC assigns the IP address and mask, and default route, to each device via DHCP.  Devices on different subnets reach each other via their default gateway -- the VPC's router -- and VPC network's router automatically has implicit routes already in place for each subnet in the VPC.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot but I could not ping any of them.

Comment: Did you change any of the VPC Network ACLs from their "allow all" defaults?  And remove those routes you added?  If you can access both of these devices, then they have their default routes, and if both SGs allow All ICMP from 0.0.0.0/0 then you should be able to ping.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  VPC Network ACLs has not been changed, it is 'ALL TRAFFIC'.  I did not remove any routes from the route table.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is it working now. I checked SGs and it was only the source IP address where the traffic can be sent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Static Route rule `ip route 172.0.1.0 255.255.255.240 172.0.1.29` and disabling Source/Destination Check for the instance must be done.